# Customizing URL of resources in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, routes

I have an application that have these three models: `Doctor`, `Patient` and `Admin` that inherits from `User` model. Each of these three models has their own views and controllers but same login form. Below, there is the method for logging user in.

```
    // session_controller.rb
      def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid e-mail/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

and routes for redirecting `redirect_to user` call to the model-specific view.

```
# routes.rb

resources :patients, :doctors, :admins
```

Until here, it all works well and I am redirected to the URI's such as **/patients/1** or **/doctors/2**. However, I do not want user ID to be seen in the URL. How can I change it to a custom one such as **/:username** or **/** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to achive it:

- Assuming that you use some helper method like current_user, you can create e.g. route /profile pointing to profile_controller#show. No matter who you are (doctor, patient, admin), you're logged in and your "resource" ID is not visible in the url.
  *Edited: If you're not sure, how to add authentication to RoR apps properly, please have a look at "warden" gem (or more complex "devise", which has warden under the hood)*
- You can use "friendly" urls, which in most cases uses urls like "1-username" etc. You can of course remove the ID part (1-xx), but you still have to provide unique identifier (it could be resource's uuid, unique combination of name/email with some field etc.). More information about friendly urls here: https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the to_params method in your models.

Check this page http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

you can do something like

```
def to_param
   id + "-" + username
end
```

If you remove the id from the to_param method, you will have to update the way you get the users/doctors/etc

For example if you only have the username in the to_param method you will have to get the user with

```
User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

Comment: I am new to this so this may sound ridiculous. I was thinking of getting the ID from session instead of params directly. Isn't it possible?

Comment: oh sure you can do that too. But if you want to see the page of another doctor for example, you will have to get the id from somewhere.